# What is the difference between increase and delta in PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

Given a counter like `http_requests_total` that increases over a given time range, what is the difference in calculating `delta(http_requests_total[5m])` and `increase(http_requests_total[5m])`?

As far as I understood the documentation, `delta` calculates the difference between the start and end value of the time range. `increase` calculates the `rate` and then multiplies it with the time range.

But what is the actual difference? Wouldn't these two values always be the same?

Like, say I had the following values, each value is at the next second:

```
t0: 5
t1: 11
t2: 18
t3: 30
```

Then `delta` would be `30 - 5 = 25`. The `rate` would be the average of the individual deltas, which would be `8.333`. If I multiply this with the time range `3`, then I get `25` again. So what is actually the difference between the two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`delta` will fail when your counter will be reset (when it will start counting from 0 again), while `increase`/`rate` will detect that and adjust result accordingly.
So with:

```
t0: 5
t1: 11
t2: 28
t3: 4
t4: 40
```

with `delta` you'll probably get `40 - 5 = 35`, while `increase` will probably calculate something similar to `(28-5)+40 = 63`

Comment: Makes sense, but wouldn't that make `delta` useless for most counters? i.e. I could never know if the value is wrong because the container restarted...

Comment: Yes, you should not use it with counters. See the Prometheus documentation: "delta should only be used with gauges and native histograms where the components behave like gauges (so-called gauge histograms)".

Comment: With slowly decreasing counter, the increase() returns a crazy big postive result. So I have to use delta().